# If anything, weren't the first people in orbit the first who broke the sound barrier in free fall?

Tags: physics, sound

Felix Baumgartner and Alan Eustace are said to have broken the sound barrier during their space jumps. But in space, there is no sound. In fact, they were still within the Earth's atmosphere so there would still be weak sound waves, but anyone who went to orbit orbited within the Earth's atmosphere as well. Therefore, Yuri Gagarin may be considered the first man who broke the sound barrier in free fall; he didn't do so in relation to his surrounding atmosphere, however.

Therefore, the first person to break the sound barrier in his own free fall would be the first orbital spacewalker Alexey Leonov. But if one doesn't count him because he was tethered to his spacecraft, the first person who broke the sound barrier in free fall would be Bruce McCandless, or not?

Comment: "In Space No One Can Hear You (break the sounds barrier, or) Scream"

Comment: shock formation is probably the best criteria for whether the sound barrier is being broken, which doesn't seem to be met for the spacewalkers

Comment: @ErinAnne ... I think "breaking the sound barrier" means travelling through a gas faster than the speed of sound in that gas, at that temperature. Shock wave formation depends on gas density, but speed of sound does not.

Comment: @Woody what "barrier" is there if there's no shock wave?

Comment: @ErinAnne ... Oxford defines barrier as " obstacle that prevents movement or access". The "sound barrier" is more a media term than a scientific term, coined when no one had "broken" it. The Cold War needed victories, and Chuck provided one. It is analogous to "hull speed" in marine design: supposedly the speed which cannot be exceeded by a displacement hull. But every duck can break it.

Comment: @Woody a barrier not being insurmountable doesn't make it not a barrier (see e.g. virtually every door or fence).  Both the increased drag and the qualitative differences in behavior between sub/trans/supersonic regimes make it clear why these skydivers were celebrated for their speed and the spacewalkers were celebrated for different things.

Answer (score 1):

The sound barrier - or speed of sound - does not exist in space, so no - you can only break the sound barrier in atmosphere.

Comment: acoustic waves exist in space and played a large role in modelling the structure of the early universe following the Big Bang. See reference cited in Erin Anne's comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240424/57036

Answer (score -1):

Answer: **Correct**. Alexey Leonov, during EVA,  was the first person to break the sound barrier in free fall.

Space is not an absolute vacuum. It has acoustic waves. This is widely recognized in astrophysics and used to model the evolution of the universe. This Physics SE question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162184/what-is-the-speed-of-sound-in-space/240424#240424 has an excellent answer on the speed of sound in space.

The speed of sound is the average velocity of gas molecules making up the gas in question. This velocity is proportional to the square root of the absolute temperature and inversely proportional to the average molecular weight of the molecules making up the gas.

In an absolute vacuum the speed of sound has no meaning because there are no molecules. But space, at least in the solar system, is not an absolute vacuum, especially in LEO.
In LEO there are molecules. Where there are molecules, there is temperature. And where there is temperature, there is the speed of sound.

Temperatures in the thermosphere above 120km altitude can be 500-1500*C, depending on solar activity. This gives the speed of sound as 557-845 m/sec

[image]

https://www.windows2universe.org/earth/images/profile_jpg_image.html

So EVA astronauts are definitely breaking the sound barrier. And they are in free fall. They are unlikely to receive complaints about their sonic boom.

Comment: I was curious about if the increasing mean free path length meant the equations for speed of sound would change in the thermosphere; while looking I stumbled across [this Physics SE answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240424/57036) showing an experimental result with GOCE clocking infrasound from a tsunami at pretty close to the speeds you derived (a bit faster, but not wildly so).  Apparently ever-more rarefied gases cut off the maximum frequency of sound waves.  Neat.

Comment: "In an absolute vacuum the speed of sound has no meaning because there are no molecules." That is true, but if there are only very few molecules, the probability for a collision between two molecules is very small, sound could not be transmitted and the speed of sound is undefined.

Comment: @ErinAnne ... excellent find. Apparently,  following the Big Bang, acoustic waves played a big part in the density variations which ultimately led to galaxy formation. Music of the Spheres !

Comment: @Uwe ... the free path length sets an upper limit on the frequency which can be transmitted through a gas (The path length must be shorter than the wavelength). But there is no lower limit. Acoustic waves in space are dominated by low frequencies. Acoustic waves in space  play a large role in cosmology. See the Physics SE answer quoted in Erin Anne's answer.

Comment: @Woody I have a [not-very-related question for you in a chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/144316/quick-question-on-comment-style)